# How to refer to array name

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I am trying to create such function in JS:

```
const removeObjectFromArray = (id, array) => {
    const newArray = array.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    array = newArray;
}
```

Everything would be great but the last line is not working. I want it to refer to array name (in this case incomeArray) and overwite the variable but it doesn't work this way.

Can you please help me finding a solution?

Comment: Variables are passed by value, not by reference. Assigning to `array` doesn't assign to the caller's variable. The function should return the new array, then the caller can assign it back to the variable. `xxx = removeObjectFromArray('someid', xxx);`

Comment: Just to confuse things, while the parameter doesn't reference the passed variable, both `myArray` and `array` do reference the same array. Thus, while you can't reassign `array` and see the change in `myArray`, you *can* mutate `array` and the change will be reflected in `myArray`. So instead of `array = newArray` you could `array.splice(0, array.length, ...newArray);` (don't do this, use the answer below)

Answer (score 4):

You can just return the value and use it that way.

```js
const removeObjectFromArray = (id, array) => {
    return array.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
}

let myArray = [{id:5}, {id:10}];
myArray = removeObjectFromArray( 10,  myArray);
// myArray is now [{id:5}]
```